# Is there a word to describe the unintelligent/streety way some people talk?

Tags: single-word-requests, slang, colloquialisms

This type of communication frequently leaves the 'g' off the end of words. "Talking" becomes "talkin'".

Also, it combines certain small phrases into one. "What's that?" becomes "Wuzzat?"

The best example I can think of would be the comic book characters Nick Fury and Howard the Duck who speak like this in the comics.

Comment: Probably [AAVE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AAVE) but there isn't much to go on in the question.

Comment: What's wrong with just "street" or "street-talk". I've heard them said before.

Comment: There's *slang*, there are *street*, *colloquial*, *teen lingo*, ... and there's even the beautiful rustic. No one-size-fits term would be nice here.

Comment: I don't agree with calling this *unintelligent* in any sense at all.

Comment: In support of Kris's comment, here's what the leading British linguist David Crystal has said on this subject:

‘There is of course no correlation whatever between the sound of a language or dialect and the level of intelligence or sociability of its speakers. The only reason we might think 
otherwise is because for generations people were told so by their – for want of a better word – "betters".’

Comment: I've submitted the asking of this question to yoisthisracist.com. I'll get back to you with any response.

Comment: In my experience, people who characterize such a phenomenon as "unintelligent" lack the self-awareness to realize that they themselves are perpetrators in some form.

Comment: *Absolutely every one* "drops" certain letters and "combines" certain words. Try saying "gas station" with a full-on glottal stop in there and think about how weird it sounds -- the standard pronunciation is "ga-station."

Answer (score 9):

I think I would put this in the category of [***colloquial***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/colloquial) speech:

> *colloquial*:
>
> 1. Characteristic of or appropriate to the spoken language or to
>    writing that seeks the effect of speech; informal.
> 2. Relating to conversation; conversational.

Individual instances of this, "*Whazzup?*" for example, would be called *colloquialisms*.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on whether you want to be disparaging, neutral, or approving, you could refer to this as [sloppy](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-cobuild/sloppy%20speech)[/slurred](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relaxed_pronunciation), [casual](http://www.phrasemix.com/concepts/casual-speech)[/colloquial/familiar/informal](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/colloquial) , or [natural/formal/careful](http://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/Natural+speech) speech.

Answer (score 3):

The term *vernacular* might fit here. [Merriam-Webster's entry says:](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vernacular)

> **a:** using a language or dialect native to a region or country rather than a literary, cultured, or foreign language
>
> **b:** of, relating to, or being a **nonstandard** language or dialect of a place, region, or country

It is [elsewhere defined as:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/vernacular)

> a. The **everyday language** spoken by a people as distinguished from the literary language. See Synonyms at *dialect*.
>
> b. A variety of such **everyday language** specific to a social group or region: *the vernaculars of New York City.*

Answer (score 0):

'Basilect' might be what you are looking for. From OED:

*basilect, n.*

*Pronunciation:  /ˈbæsɪlɛkt/*

*In a post-creole community, the social dialect that is most closely related to the creole and furthest removed from the standard language; also, the least prestigious or ‘lowest’ variety of any language.*

Answer (score -1):

"Ghetto" also comes to mind. (@FumbleFingers)

Comment: If you're an awful person.